# Как отобразить на странице thymeleaf авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

Авторизация пользователя происходит по Email и пароль. Как сделать чтобы на странице отображался авторизованный пользователь не по Email, а по любому другому полю из базы.
Использую UserDetailsService.

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws 
 UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
```

Чтобы вернуть залогиненного пользователя использую метод

```
 public String findLoggedInUsername() {
    Object userDetails = 
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
    if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
        return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div th:text="${#authentication.name}"></div>
```